# generator-karma does not satisfy its siblings' peerDependencies requirements

Tags: node.js, angularjs, generator, yeoman, karma-runner

The same notorious error

```
npm ERR! peerinvalid The package generator-karma does not satisfy its siblings' peerDependencies requirements!
npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer generator-angular@0.7.1 wants generator-karma@~0.6.0
npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer generator-angular-ui-router@0.5.3 wants generator-karma@~0.5.0

npm ERR! System Darwin 12.5.0
npm ERR! command "node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install" "-g" "generator-angular"
npm ERR! cwd /Users/dmitrizaitsev/Dropbox/Priv/APP/my-yo-project
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.24
npm ERR! npm -v 1.3.21
npm ERR! code EPEERINVALID
```

comes from installation various packages, e.g. for

```
npm update -g yo
```

The only found advice to uninstall `generator-karma` does not help - it re-installs back.

Any better explanation of why it happens and working solution?

Comment: Just making it clear, you did try `sudo npm update -g generator-karma` correct? You may also try looking at `/node_modules/generator-karma/package.json`, and view the version to see if it's above equal or above 0.6.0.

Comment: Yes, I tried that too. I was able to get rid of that error by uninstalling `generator-angular-ui-router`, which seems to use older version of `generator-karma`. Kind of annoying there is no better way.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You need to update all of your globally installed NPM packages. Run this command from your console:

```
npm update -g
```

This command will update all the packages listed to the latest version (specified by the tag config).

It will also install missing packages.

When you specify the -g flag, this command will update globally installed packages. If no package name is specified, all packages in the specified location (global or local) will be updated.

Comment: Just running this fixed the problem for me

Comment: This command totally screwed npm for me. It came back with lot of error and now I have this : -bash: /usr/local/bin/npm: No such file or directory. Think twice before running this

Comment: @0x1gene `npm` has destructive behavior of deleting itself sometimes upon failure. You can simply restore it by re-installing node. Annoying but works.

Comment: `Cannot find module '/Users/username/.npm-packages/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/build.js'`

Answer (score 47):

Try running `npm uninstall -g generator-karma`

Comment: Any explanation what exactly happens here?

Comment: not really sorry, I just had this generator somehow installed globally and uninstalling it fixed it. I reckon there have been a lot of changes during different versions of karma.

Comment: Good call. I ran into this when trying to install webpack and this solution satisfies it as well.

Comment: This worked for me. Thanks! I then re-installed karma afterwards and everything was happy.

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar issue and I did this in terminal:

`rm -rf /usr/local/lib/node_modules/karma-*`

and then updated the `package.json`:

```
  "devDependencies": {
    "karma": "0.12.0",
    ...
  }
```

then reinstall

`sudo npm install karma`

It worked for me

Comment: You should **never** `sudo npm` -- see http://stackoverflow.com/a/29787667/1614973

Answer (score 2):

It fixed it by running this command, which installs the latest version from GitHub:

```
$ npm install -g git://github.com/iamblue/generator-angular-ui-router.git
```

Comment: I had tried all the others - for Windows your solution was the only one that worked

Answer (score 1):

i was able to install simply by:

```
npm install karma-generator
```

Guess it installs a later version of Karma.  I was able to successfully install generator-angular after that.  Was able to get coffeescript going as well after doing the above.

Answer (score 0):

I had permissions issues with some of the directories under /usr/local/lib/node_modules. I must have installed some packages with sudo but most under my own user id. I solved this issue on a Mac with these commands:

```
sudo chown -R `whoami` /usr/local/lib/node_modules/
sudo chgrp -R admin /usr/local/lib/node_modules/
```