# Jhispter installation: The package karma does not satisfy its siblings' peerDependencies requirements

Tags: npm, yeoman, karma-runner, yeoman-generator, jhipster

I'm trying to generete jhipster project by yo. But when I run it, a strange error occurs: `The package karma does not satisfy its siblings' peerDependencies requirements!`
I uninstalled the nodejs completely and installed it again, but still same error.
When I search for there are some solution advices like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21140931/generator-karma-does-not-satisfy-its-siblings-peerdependencies-requirements) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19455019/npm-err-peerinvalid-the-package-generator-karma-does-not-satisfy-its-siblings-p).

I have 64 bit win7, 
node -v v0.10.26
npm -v 1.4.3

```
error peerinvalid The package karma does not satisfy its siblings' peerDependencies requirements!
error peerinvalid Peer karma-script-launcher@0.1.0 wants karma@>=0.9
error peerinvalid Peer karma-chrome-launcher@0.1.2 wants karma@>=0.9.3
error peerinvalid Peer karma-html2js-preprocessor@0.1.0 wants karma@>=0.9
error peerinvalid Peer karma-jasmine@0.1.5 wants karma@>=0.9
error peerinvalid Peer karma-requirejs@0.2.1 wants karma@>=0.9
error peerinvalid Peer karma-phantomjs-launcher@0.1.2 wants karma@>=0.9
error peerinvalid Peer grunt-karma@0.7.3 wants karma@~0.12.0
error System Windows_NT 6.1.7601
error command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install"
error cwd C:\Users\EXT0182703\LuckyShoot
error node -v v0.10.26
error npm -v 1.4.3
error code EPEERINVALID
verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

Comment: Received a similar error with the AngularJS tutorial.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We released yesterday the version 0.11 that fixes this problem. 
Try it. http://jhipster.github.io/2014/02/19/jhipster-release-0.11.0.html

Comment: This update worked, Thanks for your help and for great project :)

Answer (score 5):

I had a similar issue and I did this in terminal:

`rm -rf /usr/local/lib/node_modules/karma-*`

and then updated the `package.json`:

```
  "devDependencies": {
    "karma": "0.12.0",
    ...
  }
```

then reinstall

`sudo npm install karma`

It worked for me