# Getting Exception with newversion 0.11

Tags: npm, karma-runner, jhipster

i have getting this error while creating project with jhipster new version 0.11.

```
error peerinvalid The package karma does not satisfy its siblings' peerDependencies requirements!
    error peerinvalid Peer karma-script-launcher@0.1.0 wants karma@>=0.9
    error peerinvalid Peer karma-chrome-launcher@0.1.2 wants karma@>=0.9.3
    error peerinvalid Peer karma-html2js-preprocessor@0.1.0 wants karma@>=0.9
    error peerinvalid Peer karma-jasmine@0.1.5 wants karma@>=0.9
    error peerinvalid Peer karma-requirejs@0.2.1 wants karma@>=0.9
    error peerinvalid Peer karma-phantomjs-launcher@0.1.2 wants karma@>=0.9
    error peerinvalid Peer grunt-karma@0.7.3 wants karma@~0.12.0
    error System Windows_NT 6.1.7600
    error command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install"
    error cwd D:\Update To 0.11\demo1
```

Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

This error has been already answered in another thread.

Please read it - [Jhispter installation: The package karma does not satisfy its siblings' peerDependencies requirements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22364960/jhispter-installation-the-package-karma-does-not-satisfy-its-siblings-peerdepe)